# CircleCI Run JUnit Tests on Compiled Artifacts

Tags: java, gradle, junit, circleci

I have a java project built with Gradle in CircleCI.  This java project consists entirely of Selenium tests + framework that run on a pre-existing environment with SauceLabs.  I'd like to take the artifacts I'm generating (jar file) and let other team use it to exercise the my tests as part of their own pre-deploy test process but I'm not sure how I can accomplish this.

What would the yaml file look like to run JUnit tests on a jar file for CircleCI?  I've spent a good amount of time looking for answers online and I can't seem to find anything that meets this use case.

Comment: Why can't you just declare a test dependency on the jar and then run ./gradlew test?  That said, it's unclear to me what the purpose is of getting downstream teams to run *your* tests as part of *their* build process!

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I don't want downstream teams to have to download and compile the entire automation project, it'd much rather have a compile artifact that can easily be run during a deployment phase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally figured out how to do this.  Below are some excerpts from my circle.yml files.

1. Generate and Save the artifacts in the automation project.

> ```
> compile:
>   post:
>     - ./gradlew shadowJar
>     - mkdir -p $CIRCLE_ARTIFACTS/build/libs
>     - cp build/libs/* $CIRCLE_ARTIFACTS/build/libs
> ```

2. Download those artifacts in some other build project

> ```
> dependencies:
>   pre:
>     # Install JQ - used when fetching automation artifacts
>     - sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install jq
>     - curl "https://circleci.com/api/v1.1/project/github/:org/:project/latest/artifacts?build=master&filter=successful&circle-token=$TOKEN" >> artifacts.txt
>     - mkdir -p $HOME/automation
>   post:
>     # Fetch our UI automation jar
>     - echo export ART_URL=$(cat artifacts.txt | jq '[.[]? | select(.url | contains("automation-ui-all.jar"))][0] | .url') >> $HOME/.circlerc
>     - wget -O $HOME/automation/automation-ui-all.jar $ART_URL?circle-token=$TOKEN
> ```

3. Execute the Tests

> ```
> - java -cp $HOME/automation/automation-ui-all.jar Main TEST_ENV=https://test.com
> ```